# Sending messages with Websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have the following html/javascript code that uses websockets to communicate with a server. It seems like I can only `send(message)` only inside the `onmessage()` and `onopen()` functions. How can I send data outside of those functions ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebSocketTest() {
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:57252/");

                ws.onopen = function () {
                    ws.send("Hi, from the client."); // this works
                    alert("Connection opened...");
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                        alert("Message received..." + event.data);
                };

                ws.onclose = function () {
                    alert("Connection closed...");
                };

                ws.send("Hi, from the client."); // doesn't work
                ws.send("Hi, from the client."); // doesn't work
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sse">
    <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably experiencing a race condition where you try to perform a `send` command even though the socket may not have been opened yet. There's an important note [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) that describes this behavior:

> As establishing a connection is asynchronous and prone to failure there is no guarantee that calling the send() method immediately after creating a WebSocket object will be successful.

You, essentially, are calling the send method immediately after creating a WebSocket.

If you move that logic to a function and call that function when you know the connection has been open, you might be fine.  For example, try moving the code into a timeout or another function that can be manually triggered after you know the socket connection has been established:

```
function sendMyMessages() {
    ws.send("Hi, from the client.");
    ws.send("Hi, from the client.");
}

<button onclick="sendMyMessages()">Test</button>
```

Comment: "after you know the socket connection has been established"   ---- how do we know that the connection is opened?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect You either listen for the `onopen` event or check the `readyState` of the connection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants

Answer (score 2):

Because `onopen` is an asynchronous event.

It's similar to doing this:

```
var value;
$.ajax({
   url: '/post/data',
   success: function(response) {
        value = response;
   }
});

alert(value);
```

What do we get in the alert? `undefined`.

The websocket works in a similar manner, you cannot `send` until the connection has finished opening. It opens asynchronously. Therefore, anytime you try to use `send`, you must ensure that the connection is already open. Right now, you are trying to synchronously use those `send` calls, before the connection is actually open.

Answer (score 0):

This is the html file of Sanic webserver websocket demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/feed'),
            messages = document.createElement('ul');
        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                message = document.createElement('li'),
                content = document.createTextNode('Received: ' + event.data);
            message.appendChild(content);
            messages.appendChild(message);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(messages);
        window.setInterval(function() {
            data = 'bye!'
            ws.send(data);
            var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                message = document.createElement('li'),
                content = document.createTextNode('Sent: ' + data);
            message.appendChild(content);
            messages.appendChild(message);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
```